# Changing Tomcat properties dynamically in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, application.properties

Generally, I specify Tomcat properties in the application.properties file of my Spring Boot application. Is there any way to change some of those properties (which can be changed) dynamically, in the runtime? May be, by hitting an endpoint?

If not, is there any other way to make them dynamic from within the application code (and not the properties file)?

There are some libraries that can be configured both from the application.properties and dynamically as well (using endpoints). Does Tomcat provide any such mechanism?

Comment: I don't think, it can be possible. As those configurations are needed to run the server.

Comment: For server.port, I understand. but aren't there other properties as well?

Comment: well nobody is stopping u from creating ur own custom solution. Create a Hashmap inside of your code and call it internal properties. And then only lookup properties if they are not specified in your internal map properties and after that feel free to update ur internal map whenever. You can even update it with api requests if you so like. Alternative would be Spring Cloud Config - externalizing your configuration to the cloud

Comment: But, how do I override or dynamically set specific Tomcat properties like server.max-http-header-size or connection-timeout? I used to set up them in the properties file only.

Comment: [Refreshscope](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#_refresh_scope) can be your friend or not. I wouldn't change anything in tomcat dynamically unless I know what am I doing. Keep in mind refresh scope uses proxying and it can probably throw away the bean being used at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. You can configure and hit endpoints to reconfigure:

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/reference/html/

Comment: But, this would mean an internal restart, right? How to do this in local and without restarting?